# Syntax problem while passing props to styled components

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
${({ left }) =>
    css`
      margin-${left ? 'right' : 'left'}: 30vw;
    `};
```

This is being used in a style component, when I pass the left prop using the styled component it doesn't work, I think there is a problem with the syntax. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: What's the type of left variable?

Comment: Im sending it as a string

Comment: If left is a string that could be 'left' or 'right' you can do `margin-${left}`: 30vw

Comment: could you try logging the value of left and check if it is string itself